# How to use by navArgs in navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, arguments

I want to use `by navArgs()` get `ProtocolFragmentArgs`. But studio prompt me `navArgs` needs to be generic, and I do not know anything about this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you please use the inline code to for better code clarity? [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193323/how-to-enter-code-snippets-in-posts-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

you could try to send the data as a bundle for now and check if it is working. I am currently facing the same problem. Lets both figure it out.I did this for now:

in the startFragment

```
var bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putParcelable("object",song)
    v.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_songListFragment_to_playerFragment,bundle)
```

in the receiving fragment

```
val mSong = arguments?.getParcelable<Song>("object")
    v.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_title).text = mSong?.title
    Toast.makeText(context, "${mSong?.title}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

once i figure it out i will post it here.

Comment: Any update on this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: u can use navigation to ccreate new parcelables and pass the data through navigation

Comment: This is old way of doing it already